# How can I rotate a part in Altium without an collision error?

Tags: altium

When I select a component when its rotated 0 degrees, 90 degrees or anything that is a multiple of 90 degrees, I get get a selection like seen below with C62. Notice how the selection highlights the component perfect.

[image]

Now when I rotate that component by 315 degrees, the selected component is actually much larger. It doesn't fit the component as tightly as the previous image.

[image]

When I move the rotated component near another rotated component, I get a collision error. It's violating the default collision rule of 10 mils.

[image]

If I change the rule such that the horizontal and vertical collision value is 0 mils, my error goes away, but I notice that I can move components onto each other without triggering a violation. Which is not what I want.

How I can rotate a part and not generate errors collisions error (when in reality, there is no collision) ?I believe its something to do with that highlighted box it, because the error only happens at the intersection of those boxes.

Comment: Too lazy to write a proper answer, but you need to generate 3D bodies for your parts. Altium uses enclosing rectangles to do collision detection if you have not defined a 3D body for the part.

Comment: @ConnorWolf HA! Looks like you're right. All my components that have this issue are the ones that do not have a 3d body.

Comment: you can also disable collision and just rely on pad overlapping/net clearance issues, but if you have lots of special mechanical 3D bodies this is not the best

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this was as @ConnorWolf has mentioned in the comments.

"Too lazy to write a proper answer, but you need to generate 3D bodies for your parts. Altium uses enclosing rectangles to do collision detection if you have not defined a 3D body for the part."

Adding 3D bodies solved this problem when rotating parts other than by 90deg increments.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a 3D model for your part, you can create a shape direclty in the PCB editor. Go to:

> Tools > Manage 3D Bodies for Components on Board

You will see the dialog shown below. Select your component and go through the list of options in the Interactive tab. You can select more than one outline, if needed.

[image: Component Body Manager]

The image on the left shows you the current setup, while the image on the right shows you the currently selected shape. Here's what I get after selecting a few more shapes (note that the shape is no longer rectangular):

[image]

Now Altium will will maintain the correct outline even if you rotate the component.

Comment: I have a correct 3D body shape created by Altium's component wizard, however this problem still exist.

Comment: @VIPPER If you cannot find an answer among the existing questions, you should start a new question and provide some more details.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need another solution, to avoid the collision error, keep in mind the rectangle enclosing the part.  If the rectangle "touches" another rectangle, then the error is reported.