# Altium - Component outline

Tags: pcb, altium

The default outline selection of a component is rectangular:
[image: 1]

Is there a way to set it to follow the real outline?:
[image: 2]]

I'd like to do it to be able to place components in the middle without adding a rule that ignores that component's clearance.

Comment: Yeah.. you need to add a 3D model to the footprint if you don't want the outline to be a rectangle..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rotate a part in Altium without an collision error?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159886/how-can-i-rotate-a-part-in-altium-without-an-collision-error)

Answer (score 2):

You can either do this in the library by adding a 3D model or an extruded body, or directly in the PCB editor. Adding models in the library is quite simple, so I'll focus on the PCB method.

To do this in the PCB tool, go to:

> Tools > Manage 3D Bodies for Components on Board

You will see the dialog shown below. Select your component and go through the list of options in the Interactive tab. You can select more than one outline, if needed.

[image: Component Body Manager]

The image on the left shows you the current setup, while the image on the right shows you the currently selected shape. Here's what I get after selecting a few more shapes (note that the shape is no longer rectangular):

[image]